# iOS is it possible to convert CLLocation into some sort of XYZ metric coordinate system?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-location, augmented-reality

I'm building an augmented reality game, and working with CLLocation is rather cumbersome.

**Is there some way to locally approximate CLLocation as XYZ coordinate, expressed in meters with the origin starting at some arbitrary point** (for example the initial position when the game was started)?

Lets say I'm working with a 1 mile radius and do not really care about the curvature of the earth. **Is it possible to approximate or somehow simplify the location based calculations for local position tracking?**

Alternatively, is there a coordinate system that can be used with CLLocation that also incorporates the roll, pitch, yaw of the CMAttitude as well as compass orientation?

**Clarification:** As far as I understand, the problem with latitude and longitude is that their units vary in size, depending on the position on the globe. I should've specified that X,Y,Z should be in standard units, like meters or feet.

Thank you!

Comment: Well the CLLocation coordinate already gives you x and y coordinates, and you just have to convert the altitude you get to a z coordinate.

Comment: I clarified the question to use metric coordinate system

Answer (score 1):

The Haversine formula may be useful.

I found a good article on it at http://www.jaimerios.com/?p=39 with code examples.

Answer (score -1):

You could get the initial point at the app's launch and calculate the relative points based on the user coordinates as he or she moves. Admittedly, this is not super elegant, but if you are  just trying to do some simple comparisons based on the user's location relative to an arbitrary origin, this should work.  For the Z, Alex Stone's suggestion of calculating it based on the altitude should be fine.